# Compile multiple projects

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

I have multiple themes with sass and a common folder with common options but the files should be compiled each theme css folder. It's a little complicated to explain. I want to share with you the scaffolding. I want to compile this with grunt but I don't know how to do

1. common_files

   - sass

     - common_file.scss
2. theme_foo

   - sass

     - file_one.scss
     - file_two.scss
   - css

     - style.scss
3. theme_bar

   - sass

     - file_one.scss
     - file_two.scss
   - css

     - style.scss
4. Gruntfile.js

I want to compile each theme with their own sass files and common files in their css folder.

Here is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: ['sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
      },
    },
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded', // For compressed use 'compressed'
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'sass',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: 'css',
          ext: '.css',
        },],
      },
    },
  })

  /* Load plugins  */

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');

  /* Tasks  */

  // Default task
  grunt.registerTask('default', [, 'watch']);

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Valijon I'm new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution to your problem :

1. Update your structure

```shell
├── project-dir
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── scss
│   │   │   ├── _button.scss
│   │   │   ├── _form.scss
│   │   │   ├── common.scss
│   ├── theme-foo
│   │   ├── scss
│   │   │   ├── _tag.scss
│   │   │   ├── _figure.scss
│   │   │   ├── theme-foo.scss
│   ├── theme-bar
│   │   ├── scss
│   │   │   ├── _tag.scss
│   │   │   ├── _figure.scss
│   │   │   ├── theme-bar.scss
```

2. Use main scss file of each folder (`common`, `theme-foo`, theme-bar`) to import all its files. And for theme files, import also`common.scss` file.

**E.g** : `common.scss` file :

```scss
@import 'button.scss',
        'form.scss';
```

**E.g** : `theme-foo.scss` file :

```scss
// import common style
@import 'common.scss';

// import theme style 
@import 'tag.scss',
        'form.scss';
```

3. Now you just have to compile `theme-foo.scss` and `theme-bar.scss` with [grunt-contrib-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-sass).

**E.g** :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'project-dir/theme-foo/css/theme-foo.css': 'project-dir/**/theme-foo.scss',
                    'project-dir/theme-bar/css/theme-bar.css': 'project-dir/**/theme-bar.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
};
```

Take a look [sass-guidelines](http://sass-guidelin.es) and specially [7-1 pattern](http://sass-guidelin.es/#the-7-1-pattern) to learn a lot of good practices.

Comment: Nice @Louis :) thanks a lot. I thought that I can use something like sass:foo & sass:bar to create different configurations, but your solution it's better. Regards